# Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ such that $f(\frac{k\pi}{n})=\sin(\frac{k\pi}{2})$ for $k=0,1,2…n$ then find $\int_0^\pi (f(x))^2 dx$

Tags: polynomials, definite-integrals

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ such that $$f(\frac{k\pi}{n})=\sin(\frac{k\pi}{2})$$ for $k=0,1,2…n$ then find the value of $$\int_0^\pi (f(x))^2 dx$$ in terms of $n$.
I tried by taking $$f(x)=p(x)x(x-\frac{2\pi}{n}) (x-\frac{4\pi}{n})…$$ $$f(x)-1=q(x) (x-\frac{\pi}{n}) (x-\frac{5\pi}{n})…$$ and $$f(x)+1=r(x) (x-\frac{3\pi}{n}) (x-\frac{7\pi}{n})…$$ for some polynomials $p(x),q(x)$ and $r(x)$ but now how to combine them? I also tried to find it for $n=0,1,2,3$ but couldn’t observe any pattern. Here we need to find exact expression of $f(x)$ and then integrate or is there some indirect clever method?

Comment: You can use the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial to write down an explicit expression for f(x)

Comment: Please provide an approach within JEE if possible.

Comment: I think for the moment you would want to look at Lagrange polynomials (I think they are elementary enough in a calculus class, for $n = 2$ the polynomial would be $\frac{x(x-\pi)}{(\pi/2-0)(\pi/2-\pi)}.$ I think you would want to use that the polynomial is symmetric around $x = \pi/2$ (group the terms $k\pi/n, \pi - k\pi/n$) but I don't know of an easy method to sum up the remaining terms. You can integrate the resulting $f^2(x)$ by parts and by symmetry most terms should cancel, but I don't see an easy way to simplify the work.